# Confusion about Riemann sphere

Tags: circles, stereographic-projections, riemann-sphere

I'm confused about the following. Consider a circle $C$ on the Riemann sphere with the point at infinity in its interior but not at its center. Let's say $C_1$ is its center, and $C_2$ is the center of its exterior. I'm confused about the images of $C$, $C_1$ and $C_2$ if you would apply stereographic projection on this sphere (if needed assume the sphere has radius 1 and is placed on top of the origin of the complex plane with no rotation).

More explicitly, I'm confused about this:
I *think* that what we would see now after stereographic projection is some circle in the complex plane with center the image of $C_2$. The exterior of this image circle seen in the complex plane would be the image of the interior of $C$ seen on the Riemann sphere, but then where in the complex plane is the image of $C_1$? And what even is this center? By how we defined $C$ it can't be the point at infinity (as that is stereographically projected to itself), but how could it be any other number? Seen from the complex plane we just have some circle and ask what the center of the exterior is, which could only be the point at infinity as far as I know.

I hope I made clear what the problem is. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The spherical centre of circle is not the Euclidean centre of circle.  You have $C_1,C_2$ are antipodal, i.e., $\zeta_1=1/\bar{\zeta_2}$ under stereographic projection.  It is easy to see the Euclidean diameter through $0$ contains the spherical centre and in fact it is easy enough to the spherical midpoint of that geodesic with the explicit formula of spherical distance on $\mathbb{C}$: $2\sin^{-1}\frac{\lvert z_1-z_2\rvert}{\sqrt{\lvert z_1\rvert^2+1}\sqrt{\lvert z_2\rvert^2+1}}$.

Comment: Hmm... just noticed you are using a different convention.  My above formulae assumes the sphere is the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3=\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{R}$ with the equatorial $\mathbb{C}$-plane.  Your version sitting the sphere on top of the plane would give a slightly different result.

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks for your response, but I'm still a bit confused about the following. We have that stereographic projection maps $C$ to some other circle $D$ in the complex plane. If we then view the exterior of $D$ as a disk with some center, is that center always the point at infinity? From your answer I assume that it need not be the case that the center of $C$ seen on the Riemann sphere is mapped to the center of $D$ seen in the complex plane, so maybe this is indeed the case. Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, the (spherical) centres of a circle in not going to be $0,\infty$ unless the circle is $\lvert z\rvert=r$.  For example, the spherical centre of the circle $\lvert z-\frac12\rvert=\frac12$ is mid-point on the great circular arc joining the south pole and $(1,0,0)$, i.e., $(\frac1{\sqrt2},0,-\frac1{\sqrt2})$, which does not correspond to $z=\frac12$ but instead $z=\sqrt{2}-1$.